# 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0' not working

Tags: android, google-maps, gradle

gms play services 9.4.0  giving me a failed execution for my task it and it says like this.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices
```

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 8.3.0.

And here is how I declare my gradle i cant see where is the `conflict` here thaaanks :)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

repositories {
maven {
    url "https://jitpack.io"
}
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.kun.carkila"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile files('libs/GenAsync.1.2.jar')
compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
compile files('libs/KGJsonConverter.jar')
compile files('libs/MD5Simply.jar')
compile files('libs/PhotoUtil.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.github.amigold.fundapter:library:1.0'
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
compile 'com.github.pinball83:masked-edittext:1.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

}
```

Module

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-beta2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha6'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: The solution provided in the duplicate answer does not work for me!